# What is the `edit` attr in a meta tag

Tags: html, meta-tags

I was looking at jsfiddle's code and saw these lines:

```
<meta name="description" edit="mootools shell, easy test you snippets before implementing">
<meta name="keywords" edit="mootools,javascript,javascript framework,shell,test">
<meta name="robots" edit="all">
```

I've never seen the `edit` attr before. What does it do? I couldn't find any info on w3.org or google

Comment: Perhaps it is invalid html? You can pretty much put anything into html, the browsers won't complain. I think they might be using it to provide some data for the js. That is all just a wild speculation though.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Ok I guess I am right then, thanks @RepWhoringPeeHaa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would bet it's just mistake on their part and the "edit" attribute should have been "content". Maybe you should send them a note and let them know.

Update: 
I just sent Piotr a note, letting him about it. I'll update my answer with his response (if any).

Comment: Yeah those should both be `content` attributes.

Comment: The robots tag actually invalid since "all" isn't a valid option even if content attribute was used. I asked Piotr about it as well.

Comment: @BluesRockAddict: Who's that?

Comment: I've received no response from Piotr, so I guess we won't know for sure (or maybe meta tags get fixed eventually).

Answer (score 2):

The `edit` attribute [is not valid html](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://jsfiddle.net&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0):

```
 Line 4, Column 33: there is no attribute "edit"
  <meta name="description" edit="mootools shell, easy test you snippets before …
✉
```

So this means that it is either used by jsfiddle itself to pass values onto their js, or by some web-crawlers that I do not know of.

I have checked google's crawler, but it doesn't mention any such attributes.

Comment: I kind of doubt they're using something like `easy test you snippets` in an attribute as a javascript hook for jsfiddle itself... looks more like a mistake.